# Use of int main() in flex file

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lex, bisonc++

Consider a flex file **file1.l**

```
%{
int count = 0;
%}

%%
[A-Z]* { printf("%s is a capital letter string \n", yytext);
        count++; }
.     { printf("%s not a capital letter\n", yytext); }
\n    { return 0; }
%%

int main(){
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
```

Consider another flex file **file2.l**

```
%{
int count = 0;
%}

%%
[A-Z]* { printf("%s is a capital letter string \n", yytext);
        count++; }
.     { printf("%s not a capital letter\n", yytext); }
\n    { return 0; }
%%
```

Note that **file1.l** and **file2.l** differ only in ***int main()*** part.
We use following commands on both the files.

```
flex filename.l
gcc -o filename.exe lex.yy.c -lfl
./filename.exe
```

**I observed that both the files gets executed the same way. Why is that? Does that mean *int main()* doesnot have any role?**

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about flex. This is just the result of linking with `-lfl`.

`libfl` contains a default implementation of `main()`. Like any member of a library archive, the definition of `main()` in a linked library will be used if needed. If you supply a definition in an object file, the archive member won't be used.

So your definition of `main()` is the one which is used in the case of `file1`. It differs from the one on `libfl` in that yours only calls `yylex()` once whereas the `libfl` definition calls `yylex()` in a loop until it returns 0.

`libfl` also contains a default implementation of `yywrap()`; again, it will be used only if needed. (In your examples, `yywrap()` is needed because you don't define it. Use `%option noyywrap` to remove the dependency.)

If you don't need these default definitions, linking with `-lfl` is unnecessary.

Both if these library members are specified by the Posix standard for `lex` (although in Posix the library is linked with `-ll`).